# NullPointerException when calling Firebase setUserProperty

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to collect information on what data user's are entering using Google Firebase but I keep receiving a null pointer exception, specifically

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

This is the code:

```
public class Analytics extends Activity {
    FirebaseAnalytics analytics;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(Analytics.this);
    }

    public void timer(int time) {
        String stringTime = String.valueOf(time);
        analytics.setUserProperty("Timeset", stringTime);
    }
}
```

Which is called in another file as such:

```
Analytics analytics = new Analytics();
analytics.timer(10);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you try to **instantiate that Activity by normal means** (`Analytics analytics = new Analytics();`) the **`onCreate()` method WILL NOT be called.**

```
public class Analytics {
    FirebaseAnalytics analytics;

    public Analytics(Context context)
    {
        analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(Analytics.this);
    }


    public void timer(int time) {
        String stringTime = String.valueOf(time);
        analytics.setUserProperty("Timeset", stringTime);
    }
}
```

And call it from your other activity

```
Analytics analytics = new Analytics(Activity.this);
analytics.timer(10);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, the file where I call
`Analytics analytics = new Analytics();` is a fragment so the 'Activity' keyword doesn't work. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: you can use `getActivity()` for fragment

Answer (score -1):

Where have you initialized the stringTime variable? The exception is because of uninitialized stringTime variable.